# How can I return the result of PUT request without refreshing the app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, axios

I did a PUT request which toggles the image but to see the result of it I have to refresh the app.. How can I do it without refreshing?

The code:

```
const Islbutton = props => {
  const [islIsOn, setIslIsOn] = useState(props.IslIsOn);

  const changeButtonStateIsl = () => {
    if (checkRole(role)) {
      axios
        .put("http://localhost:5000/api/bns/" + bnsName, {
          headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
          },
          islIsOn: !islIsOn
        })

        .then(response => {
          console.log(response);
        })

        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        })
        .finally(); // I assume it has to be here?
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <img
        src={islIsOn ? islon : isloff}
        onClick={() => changeButtonStateIsl()}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

If that would be SQL i would just done something like: Select *, Where IslIsOn = value;

Comment: can you post relevant portion of code of where you want to put the result? maybe a dummy component to explain what do you want.

Comment: is there a racecondition between the view and the puts recipient? else you can just do it after the response?

Comment: The .finally if empty is not required.

Comment: @Joe Yes i know but I just assume the code which will return the data from database will be there

Comment: @Estradiaz I use put request(send data to server) which works good already, all I have to do is get data(take back the updated one) now to make it work perfectly

Comment: You could try to get the updated data after the successful response of this put request. If you want to reduce the calls, then you might have to use it as a state

Comment: @vvk24 And how could I do that?;o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just need to change your state to trigger the re-render.

```
.then(response => {
    // Set the state to true or false based on your response
    ...
    setIslIsOn(true);
 })
```

If you want to trigger the change even if you get an error from your PUT, then you would set the state in the "finally" section instead.

Comment: Damn.. You gave me the idea.. The all I had to do was:   .then(response => {
setIslIsOn(!islIsOn); 
}
THANK YOU! <3